Regular and Non-regular Polygon list
I need help with my code. As you can see, the compilation is incorrect:

But I'd like some like this:

\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8] 
      % Quadrado
      \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
      \node at (1, -0.5) {Quadrado};
    
      % Pentágono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {72,144,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \node at (0, -1.5) {Pentágono};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Hexágono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {60,120,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \node at (0, -1.5) {Hexágono};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Heptágono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {51.43,102.86,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \node at (0, -1.5) {Heptágono};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Octógono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {45,90,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \node at (0, -1.5) {Octógono};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Eneágono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=15cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {40,80,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \node at (0, -1.5) {Eneágono};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Decágono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=18cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {36,72,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \node at (0, -1.5) {Decágono};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Triângulo equilátero
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,1.73) -- cycle;
        \node at (1, -0.6) {Equilátero};
        \node at (0.3, 0.2) {$60^\circ$}; 
        \node at (1.7, 0.2) {$60^\circ$}; 
        \node at (1, 1.4) {$60^\circ$};  
    \end{scope}
    
      % Triângulo isósceles
      \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm, yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,1.5) -- cycle;
        \node at (1, -0.5) {Isósceles};
        \node at (0.5, 1.2) {$\alpha$};
        \node at (1.5, 1.2) {$\alpha$};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Triângulo escaleno
      \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm, yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1.5,1.5) -- cycle;
        \node at (1, -0.5) {Escaleno};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Triângulo retângulo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm, yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1.5) -- cycle;
        \draw (1.8,0) -- (1.8,0.2) -- (2,0.2);
        \node at (1, -0.5) {Retângulo};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Triângulo obtusângulo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm, yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,0.5) -- cycle;
        \node at (1, -0.5) {Obtusângulo};
        \node at (1.5, 0.2) {> $90^\circ$};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Triângulo acutângulo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=15cm, yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,1.2) -- cycle;
        \node at (1, -0.5) {Acutângulo};
        \node at (0.7, 0.8) {< $90^\circ$};
        \node at (1.3, 0.8) {< $90^\circ$};
        \node at (1, 0.2) {< $90^\circ$};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Paralelogramo
      \begin{scope}[yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (4,2) -- (1,2) -- cycle;
        \node at (1.5, -0.5) {Paralelogramo};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Losango
      \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm, yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,2) -- (-1,1) -- cycle;
        \node at (0, -0.5) {Losango};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Trapézio
      \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm, yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (2.5,2) -- (0.5,2) -- cycle;
        \node at (1.5, -0.5) {Trapézio};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Retângulo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm, yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
        \node at (1.5, -0.5) {Retângulo};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Polígono côncavo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm, yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,1.5) -- (2,2.5) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
        \node at (1, -0.5) {Côncavo};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Polígono convexo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=15cm, yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (3,1.5) -- (1.5,2.5) -- (-0.5,1.5) -- cycle;
        \node at (1.5, -0.5) {Convexo};
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}


Something like this?

Edit:
Image now contain all shapes drawn in your question. For their drawing and writing text I use angles, backgroundsandquotes` TikZ libraries.
Since it is not clear what title of images you like to have (colored, with text showed on images) I wrote only those which are defined in the your code example. You can easily change them to the style and content as you like to have.
MWE:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                backgrounds,
                quotes,
%                shapes.geometric, 
%                
                calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,
 N/.style = {draw=gray, fill=gray!10, minimum size=20mm},
MA/.style = {angle radius = 4mm,
             angle eccentricity=#1, % angle label position!
             inner sep=1pt,
             font=\scriptsize}, 
MA/.default = 1.1,
                        ] 
      \begin{scope}
        \draw (45:1) \foreach \x in {135,225,315} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,label=below:Quadrado] {};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Pentágono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {72,144,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,label=below:Pentágono] {};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Hexágono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {60,120,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,label=below:Hexágono] {};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Heptágono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {51.43,102.86,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,label=below:Heptágono] {};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Octógono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {45,90,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,label=below:Octógono] {};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Eneágono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=15cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {40,80,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,label=below:Eneágono] {};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Decágono regular
      \begin{scope}[xshift=18cm]
        \draw (0:1) \foreach \x in {36,72,...,360} { -- (\x:1) } -- cycle;
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,label=below:Decágono] {};
      \end{scope}
%%%%    

      % Triângulo equilátero
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (-1,0) coordinate (A) -- 
              ( 1,0) coordinate (B) -- 
              ( 0,1.73) coordinate (C) -- cycle;
        \pic[MA, "\qty{60}{\degree}"]  {angle = B--A--C}; 
        \pic[MA, "\qty{60}{\degree}"]  {angle = C--B--A}; 
        \pic[MA, "\qty{60}{\degree}"]  {angle = A--C--B}; 
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,yshift=7mm, label=below:Equilátero] {};
    \end{scope}
    
      % Triângulo isósceles
      \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm, yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (-1,0) --
              ( 1,0)   to ["$\alpha$", sloped] 
              ( 0,1.5) to ["$\alpha$", sloped]  cycle;
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,yshift=7mm, label=below:Isóscales] {};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Triângulo escaleno
      \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm, yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0) -- (0.5,1.5) -- cycle;
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,yshift=7mm, label=below:Escaleno] {};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Triângulo retângulo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm, yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (-1,0) coordinate (A) -- 
              ( 1,0) coordinate (B) -- 
              ( 1,2) coordinate (C) -- cycle;
        \pic[MA, draw]    {right angle = C--B--A}; 
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,yshift=7mm, label=below:Retângulo]  {};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Triângulo obtusângulo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm, yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (-1,0) coordinate (A) -- 
              ( 1,0) coordinate (B) -- 
              ( 0,1) coordinate (C) -- cycle;
        \pic[MA, "\qty{>90}{\degree}"]  {angle = A--C--B}; 
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,yshift=7mm, label=below:Obtusângulo]  {};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Triângulo acutângulo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=15cm, yshift=-5cm]
        \draw (-1,0) coordinate (A) -- 
              ( 1,0) coordinate (B) -- 
              ( 0,1.2) coordinate (C) -- cycle;
        \pic[MA, "\qty{<90}{\degree}"]  {angle = A--C--B}; 
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,yshift=7mm, label=below:Acutângulo]  {};
      \end{scope}
%%%%    
    
      % Paralelogramo
      \begin{scope}[yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (-1,0) -- (0.5,0) -- (1,1.5) -- (-0.5,1.5) -- cycle;
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,yshift=7mm, label=below:Paralelogramo] {};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Losango
      \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm, yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,2) -- (-1,1) -- cycle;
        \scoped[on background layer]
            \node[N,yshift=7mm, label=below:Losango] {};
      \end{scope}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
      % Trapézio
      \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm, yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (2.5,2) -- (0.5,2) -- cycle;
        \node at (1.5, -0.5) {Trapézio};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Retângulo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm, yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
        \node at (1.5, -0.5) {Retângulo};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Polígono côncavo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm, yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,1.5) -- (2,2.5) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
        \node at (1, -0.5) {Côncavo};
      \end{scope}
    
      % Polígono convexo
      \begin{scope}[xshift=15cm, yshift=-10cm]
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (3,1.5) -- (1.5,2.5) -- (-0.5,1.5) -- cycle;
        \node at (1.5, -0.5) {Convexo};
      \end{scope}

